# How to upload files and images using umi

Tags: metaplex, umi

How do I upload my NFT assets using umi from Metaplex.

The docs are in this page. https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/blob/main/docs/storage.md

Is there a tutorial or code snippet of how I can do this? Any storage provider is okay. Even if it's centrialized.

Answer (score 5):

### Umi AWS Storage

Umi has an `UploaderInterface`, which you can see the documentation for [here](https://umi-docs.vercel.app/interfaces/umi.UploaderInterface.html). Umi's `umi-uploader-aws` allows you to create an `awsUploader` when you create your Umi interface:

```
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { walletAdapterIdentity } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-signer-wallet-adapters';
import { awsUploader } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-uploader-aws';
import { myProgramRepository } from '../plugins';

const umi = createUmi('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com')
  .use(walletAdapterIdentity(...))
  .use(awsUploader(...))
  .use(myProgramRepository());
```

This code snippet is from their `interfaces.md` doc which you can access [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/blob/main/docs/interfaces.md). You can read more about the AWS uploader and how it works [here](https://umi-docs.vercel.app/modules/umi_uploader_aws.html).

The code for `awsUploader` can be found [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/blob/main/packages/umi-uploader-aws/src/plugin.ts). Instead of the ellipsis, you'll want to pass in your `client` and your `bucketName` which are of type `S3Client` and `string`, respectively. If you are interested in creating and using Amazon S3 Buckets then I'd recommend checking out their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html).

### Umi NFT Storage

For NFTs specifically, Umi has the module `umi-uploader-nft-storage` which you can read more about [here](https://umi-docs.vercel.app/modules/umi_uploader_nft_storage.html). I'd recommend taking a look at the functions `createNftStorageUploader` and `nftStorageUploader`, specifically.

The Metaplex docs also contains a reference on how to upload JSON data to the storage provider of your choice using the Umi library. Their code is as follows:

```
import { nftStorage } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-uploader-nft-storage";
umi.use(nftStorage());
```

And then you can use the `upload` and `uploadJson` methods of the `uploader` interface to upload your assets and their JSON metadata:

```
import { createGenericFileFromBrowserFile } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";

// Upload the asset.
const file = await createGenericFileFromBrowserFile(event.target.files[0]);
const [fileUri] = await umi.uploader.upload([file]);

// Upload the JSON metadata.
const uri = await umi.uploader.uploadJson({
  name: "My NFT #1",
  description: "My description",
  image: fileUri,
});
```

The above code can be found [here](https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/insert-items).

Hopefully this helps! Remember to install any of the necessary npm packages before trying to use them. If you have any further questions don't hesitate to reach out! I also recommend you check out the [new Metaplex docs](https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/insert-items)